# Suggestions about how to mine information on the internet and extract text out of an image

Tags: java, image-processing, mining

I'm interested in how I can mine information on the internet and how to extract text out of an image.

So I'm searching for information on how to do this, I would like to program this on my own. Are there any papers that gives me a good explanation about mining and extracting?

Can someone help me on the way?

Kind regards,

Comment: Can you provide examples of the sort of imagines you want to OCR?

Comment: Question asking for recommendations, specially when it comes to libraries, are off-topic in Stack Overflow. But if you do try to code that somehow and have a more specific question, people will be glad to help.

Comment: All sort of images, it can be a photo with a text on.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can take a look at [`Tess4J`](http://tess4j.sourceforge.net/) which is a java wrapper for [Tesseract](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/). That being said, image processing (text extraction) usually requires some pre-processing first, removing colours and sections which you know contain no text being some of the most common.